# Trigger an action in another component through their parent in React

Tags: reactjs, react-rails

There are two components which has a parent, I would like to trigger one action in another component through their parent. So far I have tried this:

_mevent_show.js.jsx (One of the component):

```
gotoSearchPage() {
  this.props.gotoSearchPage()
},

return (
  <i className="fas fa-search"
      onClick={this.gotoSearchPage}>
  </i> )
```

_body.js.jsx (Parent)

```
gotoSearchPage() {
   this.calendar.changePropertyInCalendar()
},

render () {
  <Calendar mevents={this.state.mevents} ref={calendar => this.calendar = calendar}>
}
```

_calendar.js.jsx (The other component whose action should be triggered)

```
changePropertyInCalendar() {
  this.setState({searchPage: true})
},
```

These codes produce an error like `this.calendar is null`. I am using `react-rails` gem. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `this.calendar` exist? Can you post your parent component ? is possible that you are not accessing it correctly but we need more info to help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like your parent component (**_body**) is not controlling the `state`, as i can see the **_calendar** component is handling the `state` but it is the children and the parent component isn't able to access the `state`. So you have to structure your app as the parent is the responsible and the only one that can update the 'state' of your UI, also this will distribute the `values` through `props` or `context`.